# Spring redisTemplate, how to determine the key doesn't exist or the value is empty by access redis once?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am using java spring redisTemplate to access redis server. I want to get a value from redis by a key. The key does not exits probably, or it existed but the value is empty. But the redisTemplate always return null.

I can use this code to determine if the key exists:

```
redisTemplate.hasKey("name");
```

But the problem is that I need to access the redis server again to get the value :

```
//it always returns null when key doesn't exist or value is empty
var v = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("name");
```

Because I want the step 1 and step 2 is atomic. If I use code in step 1 to get existing or not firstly, it may be changed when execute step 2. Another reason that I think it performances better.

So could you help me please? Thank you!